# How to convert hijric date into strtotime

Tags: php, hijri

Im doing a project in php, right now i had faced a problem with hijric date conversion
I dont know how to convert hijric date into strtotime(); or how to convert hijric date into gregorian date (date is YYYY-MM-DD format)

```
$your_date = strtotime('1439-03-09');
```

This wont get the strtotime value of hijric date
Please help me solve this issue

Thank you

Comment: have you try any thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the available [Hijri to gregorian converter class](https://github.com/bkinsey808/simple_cal/blob/master/Hijri_GregorianConvert.class.php) to get gregorian  date first than use strtotime to get your required output

```
include "Hijri_GregorianConvert.class.php";
$DateConv=new Hijri_GregorianConvert;
$format="YYYY/MM/DD";
$hijriDate="1439-03-09";
$gregorianDate = $DateConv->HijriToGregorian($hijriDate,$format);
echo "Hijri to Gregorian Result: ".$gregorianDate."<br>";
echo $your_date = strtotime($gregorianDate);
```

this class also offer some additional features related to hijri date.

Comment: [Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr3c4p4v6x1zwrt/Hijri_GregorianConvert.class.php?dl=0)